# How do I write this style of rightarrow?

Tags: arrows

How can I write this style of right arrow?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like a Word-made rightarrow. So if you want it, use Word (or at least use it and copy the character). Else you probably want a LaTeX version such as `$\rightarrow$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the right arrow from the `marvosym` package, which I found using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). It looks a bit better when it is `Large`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
Surface \MVRightarrow\ Planar

Surface {\Large \MVRightarrow}\ Planar
\end{document}
```

[image]